# Python: create a boolean df from existing df, if column values equal to

Tags: python, dataframe

I noticed an error in my code and would like to use your help with my GUI.

I have a function which get a selected column name (line 3), identifies all the unique values of the column and later on create new data frames equal to the number of unique values.

I noticed an issue with the line 8,

1. firstly I am using contain which can add any rows to two or more dataframes, while the goal is to add each row to one dataframe.
2. if the column is not string the function does not work due to contains() function, since I need to use .str before that

I couldn't a function equal to contains() but which checks the equality, and I am trying to avoid loops in this case. Any help will be appreciated. thanks!

```
1) def basic_splitter():
2)     global df
3)     column = combobox_column_list.get() 
4)     unique_values = df[column].unique()
5)     for i in unique_values:
6)        
7)        # first df[] will split the original data frame into smaller data frames based on i value
8)        df_output = df[df[column].str.contains(i)]
9)        
10)       output_path = csv_xlsx_file_path + '/' + i + '.xlsx'
11)       df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name = i, index = False)
12)       label_after_split = Label(my_frame_1, text = "Saved in: " + csv_xlsx_file_path)
13)       label_after_split.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
```

Error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\orkhamir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\orkhamir\AppData\Local\Temp\1/ipykernel_1976/2220190921.py", line 76, in basic_splitter
    df_output = df[df[column].str.contains(i)]

    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

converting column to str and then run the function.

UPDATE:
I have changed the code to the following one. To solve all the issues I had previously.

```
def basic_splitter():
    global df
    column = combobox_column_list.get() 
    unique_values = df[column].unique()
        
    for i in range(len(unique_values)):
        # create a new file to store the df
        output_path = 'C:/Users/orkhamir/Desktop/New folder/' + str(unique_values[i]) + '.xlsx'    
        # create a first df where the column value is equal to first unique value
        df_output = df[df[column] == unique_values[i]]
        df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name = str(unique_values[i]), index = False)
        label_after_split = Label(my_frame_1, text = "Saved in: " + csv_xlsx_file_path)
        label_after_split.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your column is of type `string` before trying to call the `str` accessor on it. Just try:

```
df_output = df[df[column].astype('string').str.contains(i)]
```

Comment: Can you mark the answer correct if it was?